# How to convert a fetch return object to csv from a fetch API in C3.ai COVID-19 datalake?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am making some fetch API calls to the C3.ai COVID-19 datalake. How best can I convert that to a csv for easier reading? For reference, I am running the sample code below:

```
import requests, json

url = "https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/fetch/"

request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "include": "id,name,population2018",
        "limit": 500
    }
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url=url, json=request_data, headers=headers)

fetch_object = json.loads(response.text)
```

`fetch_object` is now a python `dict`. But I would like to convert it to a csv. How do I do that generically? I could fetch one or more fields, as specified in the `include` field in the `spec` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
def convert_fetchResult_to_Pandas(fetch_object, required_fields):
    fetch_objs = fetch_result["objs"]
    df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(fetch_objs))
    return df[required_fields]
```

One can then call:

```html
df = convert_fetchResult_to_Pandas(fetch_object, ["id,name,population2018"])
csv_string = df.to_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.json_normalize(fetch_object['objs'])` instead of `pd.read_json(json.dumps(fetch_object['objs']))` may be worth considering, too, depending on what you're after. It'll flatten any nested dicts in the case objects and separate the variable levels in the column names with dots.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying the open source repo [c3covid19](https://github.com/connor-makowski/c3covid19). You can find the [docs here](https://connor-makowski.github.io/c3covid19/api.html). It is a non-official c3 covid19 data lake connection wrapper for python.

Install

```
pip install c3covid19
```

Run

```
from c3covid19 import c3api

cnx=c3api()

request_data = {
    "spec": {
        "include": "id,name,population2018",
        "limit": 500
    }
}

output=cnx.request(
    data_type='outbreaklocation', 
    parameters=request_data, 
    api='fetch', 
    output_type='csv', 
    outfile='./output'
)
```